# AngularJS: changing ng-model depending on JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to update my ng-model depending on my JSON data. Depending on the input, the JSON returned can either be

```
{
   "abc_name":"name1",
   "abc_type":"type1"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "xyz_name":"someName",
  "xyz_type":"sometype"
}
```

My view currently is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="abc_name" />
```

It needs to be `ng-model="xyz_name"` if the JSON returned has keys starting with `xyz`. Similarly for other input form elements.

How do I do this? A directive? I need ng-model because this data needs to sent back to server.

I've tried a lot but can't figure out how to do this!

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use angular.fromJson?

Comment: You are asking to bind the same object to multiple properties, which is wrong in so many ways.Beside, the fact that you need to sent your data back to a server, doesn't mean that you have to bind it to the UI. I suggest revisiting your architecture because everything suggests that there is something odd behind the scene, either in the angular controller on in your API.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you update your question with enough data.

Answer (score 0):

I have questions about your architecture because I don't think you would run into an issue like this with a well designed system, but that aside ... you could use an ng-if with a truthy condition in regards to whether the property is there on your variable return:

```
<div ng-if="myControllerFunction().abc_name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myControllerFunction().abc_name"/>
</div>
<div ng-if="myControllerFunction().xyz_name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myControllerFunction().xyz_name" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at your statement of improving the architecture. If that doesn't work out I'll try this and get back to you.